# Open/closeness of subsets of natural numbers

Tags: general-topology, natural-numbers

So I've just started reading about neighbourhood and Hausdorff space. It makes me wonder if $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ is Hausdorff and why, and are sets in $\mathbb{N}$ open or closed or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $\{n\}$ and $\{m\}$ are in the power set and contain $m$ and $n$. But, they are disjoint. This demonstrates the Hausdorff property.

In fact, this holds for any discrete space.

Also, the open sets are by definition all subsets in $\mathbb{N}$. What are the closed sets? (Think about complements.)

Comment: Why are singletons open?

Comment: First, what is the power set of N?

Comment: The set of all subsets of N.

Comment: Yes. This includes singletons, right? All sets in the topology (in your case the power set) are by definition the open sets. So, the singletons are open.

Comment: Because it's a discrete space? or just in general?

Comment: The power set is the set of all subsets. Singletons are subsets. Therefore singletons are in the power set. The power set is the topology which the collection of open sets. Therefore, singletons are open. It's a discrete space because the topology is the power set.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that open sets can be defined that way. Back to the closed set; all subsets must also be closed since the complement is open by definition, right? I think I'll need to go read up more on topology to better understand it, thanks for now though :D

Answer (score 2):

Well, any topology of the form $(S,P(S))$ is the [discrete space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space). So, it's basically a collection of countably many points, with no particular connections between them. This means that every set is open. Thus it is Hausdorff, since the singletons $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are disjoint neighborhoods of any distinct $a$ and $b$ in the space.